# Global datastore for Polymer application

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm creating a global datastore `<datastore />` web component for my Polymer application. It is responsible to retrieve/alter data from/on a server.

The datastore itself offers functions like `get(query), set(object, attributes), create(attributes) and delete(object)`.

What would be the "WebComponent" way to use the `<datastore>` to offer data for other components? I'm also curious about how to two-way databinding could work between the datastore and other components.

Comment: I'd just like to clarify that the generic/pure Web Component-y way to do something can be quite different than the Polymer way to do things. If data binding is an important part of an element, you're probably going to have a lot of very Polymer-specific code -- data binding isn't standardized like Web Components is (or will be soon, at least).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm always worried about having too much Polymer-specific stuff in the application but afaik its still the closest we can get to using web-components today.

Comment: That's probably a good call. It is possible to use Polymer's polyfill for the proposed Web Components standard without using the rest of Polymer. However, (a) that's very limited compared with full Polymer, and (b) it looks like the Web Components draft will still change significantly, so your code still probably wouldn't be future-proof or match the eventual standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check out the firebase element? https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element
It provides the same functionalities as you described but with the services of Firebase.

Comment: That's a good hint. Separating auth, query behaviour and collections seems like a solid approach. Can the components also write changes to the Firebase? Also are there other elements like this one?

Comment: yes, they are using 2 way data-binding using the Firebase API, check out the implementation, it is pretty straightforward! I built some extending element myself, but it concerns more athentication and basic App service like profile management out of the box, here: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended